# Interpreting JMH Benchmark Results

Tags: benchmarking, microbenchmark, jmh

I am trying to get an understanding of approximately how fast/slow an operation is.

I have written a JMH benchmark:

```
@Benchmark
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.SampleTime)
@Warmup(iterations = 5)
@Measurement(iterations = 5, time = 5, timeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS)
fun endToEndQuery(blackhole: Blackhole, benchmarkState: BenchmarkState) {
    val executionResult =
        benchmarkState.graphql.execute(
            """
            query {
                hsql {
                    PUBLIC {
                        POSTS(where: { ID: { _lt: 2 } }) {
                            ID
                            TITLE
                        }
                    }
                  }
              }
            """
        )
    blackhole.consume(executionResult)
}
```

This gives the below results.

Is it correct to interpret these as saying *"It takes on average ~2ms to perform `graphql.execute()`"?*

Thank you in advance for any feedback =)

```
Iteration 1: 2.099 ±(99.9%) 0.034 ms/op
Iteration 2: 2.138 ±(99.9%) 0.086 ms/op
Iteration 3: 2.131 ±(99.9%) 0.037 ms/op
Iteration 4: 2.163 ±(99.9%) 0.039 ms/op
Iteration 5: 2.202 ±(99.9%) 0.037 ms/op

N = 11659
  mean =      2.146 ±(99.9%) 0.023 ms/op

benchmark summary:
Benchmark                                         Mode    Cnt   Score   Error  Units
Benchmarks.endToEndQuery                        sample  11659   2.146 ± 0.023  ms/op
Benchmarks.endToEndQuery:endToEndQuery·p0.00    sample          1.939          ms/op
Benchmarks.endToEndQuery:endToEndQuery·p0.50    sample          2.056          ms/op
Benchmarks.endToEndQuery:endToEndQuery·p0.90    sample          2.281          ms/op
Benchmarks.endToEndQuery:endToEndQuery·p0.95    sample          2.404          ms/op
Benchmarks.endToEndQuery:endToEndQuery·p0.99    sample          3.016          ms/op
Benchmarks.endToEndQuery:endToEndQuery·p0.999   sample         10.896          ms/op
Benchmarks.endToEndQuery:endToEndQuery·p0.9999  sample         48.382          ms/op
Benchmarks.endToEndQuery:endToEndQuery·p1.00    sample         55.181          ms/op
```